# Getting property from knockoutjs observablearray with id

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to look up a value in an observable array using the value of a property of one of the items. Here is some example code:

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li data-bind="text:name"></li>
  <li>Cousin: <span data-bind="text:related_id"></span></li>
</ul>​
```

JS:

```
var item = function (data){
  this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  this.related_id = ko.observable(data.related_id);
}

var related_item = function(data){
  this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

var ViewModel = function(){
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
      new item({id:1,name:'thing1',related_id:1}),
      new item({id:2,name:'thing2',related_id:2})                
    ]);

this.related_items = ko.observableArray([
    new related_item({id:1,name:'cousin it'}),
    new related_item({id:2,name:'cousin fred'})
]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
```

Fiddle with code above: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8693c/1/)

My question: What is the best way to get the related_item's name property to show where the item's related_id is currently being shown?
​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this JSFiddle here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZm7c/)

What I did was put the item and related_item "objects" into the ViewModel so that I could reference them. There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Pass the related_item itself into the item object instead of just the id.
2. Iterate through the related_items array.

JS:

```
    self.item = function (data){
        var itm = this;
        itm.id = ko.observable(data.id);
        itm.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        itm.related_id = ko.observable(data.related_id);
        //Possible solution 1
        itm.related_item = ko.observable(data.related_item); 
        //Possible solution 2
        itm.related_item_name = ko.computed(function() {
            tmp = '';
            $.each(self.related_items(), function(idx, elem) {
                if (elem.id() === itm.related_id()) {
                    tmp = elem.name();
                    return false; //break out of the $.each loop
                }
            });
            return tmp;
        });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
<li data-bind="text:name"></li>
   <li>Cousin: <span data-bind="text:related_id"></span></li>
   <li>(soln 1) Cousin: <span data-bind="text:related_item().name()"></span></li>
   <li>(soln 2) Cousin: <span data-bind="text:related_item_name"></span></li>
</ul>​
```

If you have no other constraints, I'd just rather do the first method and pass the entire object in instead of the ID.

Comment: Thanks for the options: I'm leaning toward the second since the actual items might be in the hundreds and both arrays will be initiated separately.

Comment: I see. If you're going to manually iterate through the array, you can skip making the array observable to save some processing time.

Comment: Lodash provides some great helper functions that let you abstract the search and filter process: http://lodash.com/